# Backbone Listen for Backbone.history events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, js-amd

I am using Backbone + requirejs for building my application, in the module below initialize function is used to load the initialize function from another two modules called "HomeView, InnerView", in this module i would like to listen for Backbone.history events. but the module didn't listen for such events.

**Router**

```
// Filename: router.js
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app/config',
'app/views/homeview',
'app/views/inner_view'
], function($, _, Backbone, Config, HomeView, InnerView) {

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    initialize: function() {

    },
    routes: {
        // Define some URL routes
        '': 'defaultRoute',
        '!/home': 'defaultRoute',
        '!/activities': 'activities',
        '!/activities/:id': 'activity',
        '!/vacancies': 'vacancies',
        '!/vacancies/:id': 'vacancies',
        // 404, not found
        '*actions': '404'
    },
    defaultRoute: function() {

        //if this route is served from inner pages, we have to trigger "close:Inner"
        Backbone.trigger('close:Inner'); 
        Backbone.current = 'Home';

    },
    activities: function(){

        Backbone.trigger('view:Activities');
        Backbone.trigger('close:'+Backbone.current);            
        Backbone.current = 'Activities';            

    },
    activity: function(id){

        Backbone.trigger('close:' + Backbone.current);
        Backbone.current = 'Activity';   

    },
    vacancies: function(){

    },     
    404: function(actions) {

        // We have no matching route, lets display 404
        $('.content_wapper').html(actions + " no such page on the system");

    }

});

var initialize = function() {

    HomeView.initialize();
    InnerView.initialize();                

    Backbone.appRouter = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();

};

return {
    initialize: initialize
};
});
```

**What is wrong that prevent me from listening to the event of backbone.history inside another view ?**

**Innerview Module**

```
 // Filename: views/boilerplate.js
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'app/config',
'text!templates/inner_header.html',
'bootbox',
'text!templates/breadcrumb.html',
'purl'
], function($, _, Backbone, Config, inner_header_template, bootbox, breadcrumbTemplate) {

var url = $.url(),
    InnerView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $(".header_content"),
    template: _.template(inner_header_template),
    initialize: function(options) {

        Backbone.history.on('route:activities', this.activities);           

    },
    render: function() {},
    activities: function() {
        alert('activities');
    },
    events: {},
    close: function() {

        $('.top_menu').remove();
        $('.main_menu_inner').remove();
        $('.content_container').empty();
        $(this.el).unbind();
        delete this.$el; //delete the jQuery wrapped object variable
        delete this.el; //delete the variable reference to this node

    }

});

var initialize = function() {

    new InnerView();

};

return {
    initialize: initialize
};


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the events on the Backbone object not Backbone.history, try this :

```
Backbone.history.trigger('close:Inner');
```

---

You must listen on the router itself not on Backbone.history. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xu4QA/1/) that illustrate that.

Comment: I was asking on this event `Backbone.history.on('route:activities', this.activities);` and the event you mentioned works perfect for me :)

Comment: Where did you trigger the `route:activities` event ?

Comment: Inside the InnerView that was initialized into the initialize functions of the router module

Comment: Excuse me, but all I see in your example is that you bind the event `Backbone.history.on('route:activities', this.activities);` not triggering it. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, I did this as per backbone documentation, that each route triggering its event automatically. and I tested that on the router itself and it works perfect but not working on the view

Comment: I have update my answer : "route:[name]" (params) — Fired __by the router__ when a specific route is matched. If I have missed something please update the example with your problem